# Quickbooks Online REST API: Is it possible to apply Date functions in the SQL query?

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

I want to retrieve invoices in which date difference between today and DueDate is > 1 or more. Is there anyway to apply some kind of `DateDiff`?

I'm using the QuickBooks Online API indicated here:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/accounting/invoice

And issuing an SQL query via their REST API like this:

```
Operation: GET /v3/company/<realmID>/query?query=<selectStatement>
Content type: application/text
```

Where my `<selectStatement>` is something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Invoice
```

I need the equivalent to something like this that I'd do in MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM Invoice WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), DueDate) > 1
```

Can I do that with Intuit's SQL-like query REST API?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - did you mean to post this on Personal Finances SE or Super User, or are you trying to do that in code?

Comment: He's trying to do this in code. I have edited the question to make it more clear what he's trying to do, and nominated for re-opening.

Answer (score 2):

If you refer to Intuit's docs, it shows what is filterable.

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/accounting/invoice

Relevant:

```
DueDate:
optional
Date, filterable, sortable
```

There is no "date difference" type function available. Intuit's limited SQL-like query language does not support it.

You may also wish to check out the A/R Aging reports, which are specifically geared towards things like finding overdue invoices (which is what it sounds like you're trying to do).

Example:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/accounting/ar%20aging%20summary

Comment: I want to fetch all invoices details(Customer Name, Email, Balance etc) which are over due for 1 or more days.

Comment: I try to help, and I get downvoted. No, there is no way to do this with a single query. You can't do this. If you use either of the two approaches I mentioned above, you can accomplish what you're looking for, but not with a single query.

Comment: Thanks for reply And No I did not dowvote. In fact my Qs was downvoted too.